# How to generate the event of "<Return>" on entry widget with event_generate?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to generate event of "Enter" on entry with event_generate function when the code below starts.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry=Entry(root)
entry.pack()

def input(event):
    print(entry.get())

entry.bind("<Return>",input)
entry.insert(0,"aaa")
entry.focus()
entry.event_generate("<Return>")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try changing `entry.event_generate("<Return>")` to `entry.after(100, entry.event_generate, "<Return>")`.

Comment: tahnk you for yor help. it works

Comment: Your title mentions `<Return>` but your question mentions `Enter`. It's not clear exactly what you're asking.